# How to add CKEditor instances inside Controller scopes with AngularJS and CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ckeditor

He there all,

Lately I ve been experimenting with Angular JS. Everything goes nice, my controllers, services etc.

When I try to make a Div editable that is inside the ng-controller the ckeditor toolbar does not popup. Any other div outside the controller works fine.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- BEGIN Dynamic Content with AngularJS -->
    <div id="js_enabled" class="js_enabled" ng-controller="boxes_controller">
        <div class="box" ng-repeat="box in boxes" style="min-width: {[{ boxes_width }]}%; width:  {[{ boxes_width }]}%; max-width: {[{ boxes_width }]}%;">
            <p contenteditable="true"> asd</p>
            <div class='box-content'>
                    <p>
                    <b>{[{ box.title }]}</b><br/>
                    {[{ box.description }]}
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END Dynamic Content with AngularJS -->
```

The {[{}]} is interpolation override. If you can see there is a **small** 'p' element with contenteditable just for testing. That is the element that does not show the ckeditor bar. 
I tested it's not CSS. The toolbar DIV elements for the ckeditor are not even created and no errors exist.

PS. If i make any other element editable outside my controller scope, everything works well.

Comment: Is CKEditor called on dynamically created content. I think it is not. It may be done in the link function of a custom directive.

Comment: Yes I have solved it. YOu are correct it was my mistake @lib3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made it an easy directive.

Just load the ckeditor.js and code is:

```
mainApp.directive('ckEditor', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
        scope: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {}, //open for now
        link: function($scope, element, attr, ngModel, ngModelCtrl) {
            if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model you might want to remove this
            element.bind('click', function(){
                for(name in CKEDITOR.instances)
                    CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy();
                CKEDITOR.replace(element[0]);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Supports multiple instances